# Can reads occur whilst executing a bulk \copy batch of inserts

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, bulk-load, postgresql-copy

I plan to be batch inserting a large volume of rows into a Postgres table using the `\copy` command once per minute. My benchmarks show I should be able to insert about 40k rows per second, and I plan to do this for 3 or 4 seconds each minute.

Are read queries on the table blocked or impacted whilst the `\copy` dump is occurring? And I wonder the same for inserts as well?

I'm assuming as well that tables which aren't being `\copy`'d into will face no blocking issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html)

> The main advantage of using the MVCC model of concurrency control
> rather than locking is that in MVCC locks acquired for querying
> (reading) data do not conflict with locks acquired for writing data,
> and so reading never blocks writing and writing never blocks reading.

That's the beauty of the MVCC model used by Postgres.

So, **no**, readers are not blocked. Neither in the target table, nor in any other table.

Impacted? Well, bulk loading large amounts of data incurs considerable load on the system (especially I/O) which potentially impacts all other processes competing for the same resources. So if your system is already reaching some limits, readers may be impacted this way.

Rows written by your [`COPY` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) (by way of psql's `\copy`) are not visible to other transactions until the transaction is committed.

Concurrent `INSERT` commands are not blocked either - **unless** you have `UNIQUE` (or PK) constraints / indexes where writes *do* compete. Avoid race conditions with overlapping unique values! And performance can be impacted even with non-unique indexes as [writing to indexes involves some short-term locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locking-indexes.html).

Generally, keep indexes on your table to a minimum if you plan huge bulk writes every minute. Every index incurs additional costs for the write - and may bloat more than the table if write patterns are unfavorable. Autovacuum may have a hard time to keep up.